# Peewee bulk_create return id's

Tags: python, database, orm, peewee

I need to return ids if the record in peewee from bulk_create

I can do something like that

```py
from models import Table

t = Table.create(**data)
print(i.id)
```

and i get the id of a new record

But if i try

```py
t = Table.bulk_create(list[**data])
for i in t:
    print(i.id)
```

here i get an error: 't' is 'NoneType'

So how can i get ids form peewee bulk_create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peewee *does* return the list of IDs *if* you are using a database that supports the `RETURNING` clause. So, if you're using Postgresql, then peewee will return the list of IDs.

The reason to use `bulk_create()` is because it issues an efficient query -- inserting many rows at once. Sqlite and mysql only offer "last insert id".